# How to get my Id, and two textbox's value from td with jquery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a td which is made by forloop in jsp. I wanna get their id and value by jax so that i can run the edit method from servlet. however, once i declare the variable of that id and textbox's value. it returned nothing.

I am using tomcat 7, java 7, oracle and windows 10. installed jquery 3.4.0.

```
// code from jsp
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
            <tr bgcolor="pink">
                <td>社員No.</td>
                <td>ユーザーID</td>
                <td>社員名</td>
                <td>削除機能</td>
                <td>更新機能</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                for (Staff s : list1) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td id="<%=s.getId()%>"><%=s.getId()%></td>
                <td><%=s.getNo()%></td>
                <td><%=s.getName()%></td>
                <td><a href="deleteStaffServlet?id=<%=s.getId()%>" class="button">削除</a></td>
                <td>名前:<input type="text" size="10" class="userNo" name="no2"/> ユーザーID:<input
                    type="text" size="10" class="userName" name="name2" />
                    <button class="edit">更新</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
                }
                session.removeAttribute("list");
            %>
        </table>

// ajax code
$(function(){
         $(".edit").click(function(){
            var userId = $(this).parent('td').first().attr("id");
            var userNo = $(this).class('userNo').val();
            var userName = $(this).class('userName').val();
            alert(useId);
            alert(userNo);
            alert(userName);
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "editStaffServlet",
                cache : false,
                data : {
                    "userId" :userId,
                    "no2" : userNo,
                    "name2" : userName
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data && data.success) {
                        alert("OK");
                    } else {
                        alert("Error " + data.msg);
                    }
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
         })
    });

// code from servlet
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String ids = request.getParameter("userId");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(ids);
        String no = request.getParameter("no2");
        String name = request.getParameter("name2");

        StaffDao staffDao = new StaffDao();
        Staff st = new Staff(id, no, name);

        st.setId(id);
        st.setNo(no);
        st.setName(name);
        staffDao.edit(st);
        response.sendRedirect("package/staff.jsp");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

when i run debugger it got the empty id so the alert didnt showup.
How can i get those id and value correctly to run the ajax?

Comment: `var userId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).attr("id");
            var userNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('.userNo').val();
            var userName = $ $(this).closest('tr').find('.userName').val();` use this selector

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent('td')` does not have an id attribute.

You need to find the parent tr and then the first td within that.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().attr('id')
```